# How to implement a forked repo from another github account in android studio?

Tags: android, git, gradle, build

I am using [alhazmy13's MediaPicker](https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaPicker) in my `build.gradle`:

```java
implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.4'
```

So far so good until this library has a bug. When I search on StackOverflow, it looks like someone else pointed out the problem and fixed it here:
https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaPicker/issues/92#event-2397705960

However, the person who fixed it forked the repo here: https://github.com/Innova133/MediaPicker

How do I make my project use this forked repo? By including `implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.4'` it would still reference to the original repo that has the bug in it.

Please help as I am not familiar with build setting with git.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For all github repos you can use jitpack.io. You can check it for your url from [here](https://jitpack.io/#Innova133/MediaPicker/2.4.4)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It did compile for having implementation 'com.github.Innova133:MediaPicker:2.4.4', but somehow the jar file that it downloaded did not have the fix that I was looking for.  The jar that it compiled and used in running seems to the original repo without the fix.  According to https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaPicker/issues/92#event-2397705960, the fix is with commit of a5331cc.  Is there a way to point to specific commit?  I tried like  com.github.Innova133:MediaPicker:a5331cc or com.github.Innova133:MediaPicker:libary  all would fail to resolve at build.gradle.